# Audio only while streaming a mp4 file to Android Device

Tags: android, video

I 've set Wowza streaming server to stream mp4 videos to Android phones. Android phone can play the RTSP stream successfully but here It only plays audio of the file not the video.

Comment: Do you know what exact video codec are you using?

Comment: Well I 'm trying to play .mp4 file on Android device using RTSP.

Comment: Did you try to play it using build-in Android Media Player? Try to analyze (in Eclipse) LogCat output. Maybe you are using unsupported video codec.

Comment: Hi Darbat
Will do dat too. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set surface (VideoView or SurfaceView) on which you would like to display video? You have to run [setDisplay](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDisplay(android.view.SurfaceHolder)) before running playback.

Problems with video can also be caused by starting playback too early.
You should start player after surface is created. If you want to start playback at start of the Activity, you should do it on surfaceCreated event. You can listen to this event by implementing [SurfaceHolder.Callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html)

Can you provide some source codes?

You can also try to follow Android ApiDemos. Video streaming player example can be found at:

```
...android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-x\samples\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\media\MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java
```

Comment: Thanks .. darbat 
Sure I will implement the methods suggested by you. And provide the source codes.

Comment: Followed the suggested example by darbat but still the only the audio is getting played no video is getting displayed. 

 // Create a new media player and set the listeners
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            /// here I 'm setting RTSP url to video
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);